# Microsoft Small Business Server - can I run a public website in IIS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net

I am looking at installing my ASP.NET app on my client's Microsoft Small Business Server Premium Edition, but I've never used it as a platform. I need public facing IIS - obviously - and SQL Server database access. Is this possible? Can I run a public site on this platform? Are there any limitations I need to be aware of?

Also, can I install third party apps on SBS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could, it is an IIS, it has a SQL Server, and of course you can install "third party apps" (depending on the party and on the app).

But why would you? SBS would be a rather expensive web server. It has an abundance of services which a web server doesn't need and you can't completely get rid off, so it will become a nightmare for security and maintenance.

You will need a CAL for every concurrent user of it, if I understand Microsofts licensing correctly. Thus you will have a maximum of 75 concurrent users / connections.